# How to turn off all the beep sounds?

Tags: windows

I have set the Windows sound scheme to **No Sounds** and I still hear some beeps on certain actions. Is there a way to turn off these beeps too?

Comment: Coming from the sound card, or from the system speaker?

Comment: System speaker.

Answer (score 21):

I've found [this blog post](http://blog.netnerds.net/2007/05/5-ways-to-stop-windows-vista-xp-2003-from-beeping/) which suggests:

```
Start > Run > sc stop beep && sc config beep start= disabled
```

I couldn't test it myself but it should stop the beep and also disable the beep service permanently (or at least until you re-enable it), so there's no need to run it every time or set up a .bat file.

Comment: This indeed works - stops the service now and disables it from running on next boot.

Comment: "The option name includes the equal sign. A space is required between the equal sign and the value." The second one should be `sc config beep start= disabled` and it's working.

Answer (score 7):

For a GUI approach:

Start -> Run -> devmgmt.msc [Enter] -> View -> Show hidden Devices.

then in the window:

Non-Plug and Play Drivers -> Beep -> Disable.

There is also the option here to keep it like this permanently when you restart, which I think the net command will not do.

Comment: It's worth adding that this may require a reboot before it works

Comment: `Non-Plug and Play Drivers` isn't on the list in Windows 8

Answer (score 5):

start -> run -> net stop beep

Comment: This works but I think you have to run it every time you restart. If you put "net stop beep" in an empty text file called "something.bat" and then put a shortcut to it in your startup folder on the Start menu then it will always run. You can edit the shortcut to make it run minimized.

Comment: If you want it this way every time you restart your PC, I think it's better to just disable the service like you suggest in another answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows XP you can use [TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx):

1. General
2. Settings
3. Uncheck: Beep on errors

Answer (score 1):

If you're on vista, open the Volume Mixer Dialogue box in the bottom right corner of the start bar and set Windows Sounds to Mute. You have to right-click it and manually select Volume Mixer as opposed to double clicking the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had an issue where beeps were coming from my keyboard and my media keys, in particular the *mute* button played a short beep, kind of defeating the purpose when I wanted to shut my PC up.

I looked everywhere for a solution, and finally stumbled across the option when I was tinkering around with my bios settings, where there was a simple option to turn off keyboard beeps. Make sure to check there if the OS options are being ignored, especially on a notebook or other PC without an internal PC speaker.

Answer (score 0):

From [Annoyances.org](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winxp/t1151476956)

> I have found the easiest way to turn off the annoying system beep in Windows XP when 
>   adjusting the volume, is to use method 3, as suggested by fester here
>
> By following the following steps, you can turn off the beep without having to reboot.
>
> The steps are;
>
> 1. Right-click on My Computer
> 2. On the Hardware tab, click on [Device Manager]
> 3. On the "View" menu, select "Show hidden devices"
> 4. Under "Non-Plug and Play Drivers", right-click "Beep"
> 5. Click "Disable"
> 6. Answer [Yes] when asked if you really want to disable it
> 7. Answer [No] when asked if you want to reboot
> 8. Right-click "Beep" again.
> 9. Click "Properties"
> 10. On the "Driver" tab, set the Startup type to Disabled
> 11. Click [Stop]
> 12. Click [OK]
> 13. Answer [No] when asked if you want to reboot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the you can now turn this off natively in the command shell options. Go to settings by clicking on the little down arrow near the tab add plus sign. Then click on the shell you want in the left column. Then advanced. And then modify the bell notification style.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).