# How do I disable alert beeps

Tags: audio, hp-pavilion

My HP pavilion laptop is getting pretty old and the speakers no longer work properly. So I've disabled all audio devices, including disabling the light-touch volume controls at boot-up.

The one sound still here that I can't get rid of is the alert beep whenever there's an error. It's annoying at the best of times, but when your laptop has no other sounds at all it's *intensely irritating*!

Nothing I change in the windows settings or in the BIOS seems to have any effect. Any ideas how to switch them off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motherboard beeper? It's always annoying. I try not to plug it in.

Open a cmd instance, and type `net stop beep`. If that stops the beeps, then go to Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`), find `System Speaker`, and check the `Show Hidden Devices` box. Find `beep`, and disable it.

Comment: Beep is located under "Non-Plug and Play Drivers", see http://superuser.com/questions/5017/windows-how-to-turn-off-all-the-beep-sounds/5028#5028