# Make the sounds (e.g. beep) that PowerShell usually makes

Tags: powershell, conemu

In a normal PowerShell console, running `[System.Console]::Beep(500, 1000)` makes a sound.

In a PowerShell console running in ConEmu, that command does not make a sound.

The ConEmu task that opens PowerShell is `powershell.exe -new_console:a`.

How can we configure ConEmu to make a sound when we run the `Beep` command?

Oddly, I have found SuperUser questions on how to disable but not on how to enable those sounds: [ConEmu: disable bell](https://superuser.com/questions/544036/conemu-disable-bell)

Comment: Have you ever tried to search in the settings dialog?

Comment: I have not. Thank you for the tip. :-)

Comment: Neither a search for "sound" nor for "beep" in the search box surfaces a result. @Maximus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck "Suppress bells" option.

[image: ConEmu: Suppress bells]